# Rails action caching refresh after expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, action-caching

I'm looking to expire and then refresh the cache for a controller action using a publicly accessible endpoint.

In my app currently, /all returns cached json, and /update expires the cache.
You can see the existing relevant code below.
What I'd like to do is not only expire the cache but force a refresh.
So, my question is:

*Is there is a way to initiate the refresh of an action cache after expiring it, without hitting the action?*

If the answer to that is no (as I'm beginning to suspect), then what would be the best way to do this?  I require the update action to return an HTTP 200 status, not a 301 redirect so just redirecting to /all isn't an option.

**VendorsController**

```
caches_action :all, :expires_in=>2.weeks

....

def all 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => Vendor.all }
    format.html { render :json => Vendor.all }
  end
end


....

def update
  render :nothing => true
  expire_action :action => :all
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`write_fragment`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-write_fragment)

```
def update
  render :nothing => true
  expire_action :action => :all

  cache_path = ActionCachePath.new(self, {:action => :all}, false).path
  write_fragment(cache_path, render_to_string(:json => Vendor.all))
end
```

Source that may help:

- [ActionCacheFilter](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionController/Caching/Actions/ActionCacheFilter)
- [expire_action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html#method-i-expire_action)

Comment: Thanks for responding.
However, two concerns.

1. Doesn't cache_page write to the disk, whereas action caching use memcache?
2. Since I'm rendering json right in the controller (arguably not the best pattern), there's no template for `vendors/all`, and so it doesn't know how to render that to a string. 

Thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @manderson I didn't notice you were using `cache_action`. I've updated my answer to use `write_fragment` instead, it may work. I've added links to rails sources of actions caching for more informations. For the point 2, use directly `render_to_string(:json => Vendor.all)`. It should work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help.  write_fragment makes complete sense.  I wouldn't have been able to write the cache_path line without your code, but my rails-fu is growing.